# Scala : How to do GroupBy sum for String values?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have RDD[Row] :

```
  |---itemId----|----Country-------|---Type----------|
  |     11      |     US           |      Movie      | 
  |     11      |     US           |      TV         | 
  |     101     |     France       |      Movie      |
```

How to do GroupBy itemId so that I can save the result as List of json where each row is separate json object(each row in RDD) :

```
{"itemId" : 11, 
"Country": {"US" :2 },"Type": {"Movie" :1 , "TV" : 1} },
{"itemId" : 101, 
"Country": {"France" :1 },"Type": {"Movie" :1} }
```

RDD :

I tried :

```
import com.mapping.data.model.MappingUtils
import com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo


val mappingPath = "s3://.../"    
val input = sc.textFile(mappingPath)
```

The input is list of jsons where each line is json which I am mapping to the POJO class CountryInfo using MappingUtils which takes care of JSON parsing and conversion:

```
val MappingsList = input.map(x=> {
                    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfoString(x);
                    (countryInfo.getItemId(), countryInfo)
                 }).collectAsMap

MappingsList: scala.collection.Map[String,com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo] 


def showCountryInfo(x: Option[CountryInfo]) = x match {
      case Some(s) => s
   }


val events = sqlContext.sql( "select itemId  EventList")

val itemList =  events.map(row => {
    val itemId = row.getAs[String](1);
    val çountryInfo =  showTitleInfo(MappingsList.get(itemId));
    val country = if (countryInfo.getCountry() == 'unknown)' "US" else countryInfo.getCountry()
    val type = countryInfo.getType()

    Row(itemId, country, type)
      })
```

Can some one let me know how can I achieve this ?

Thank You!

Comment: Did the RDD[Row] come from a DataFrame/DataSet? Working with RDD[Row] is generally not ideal although still doable.

Comment: I created the RDD from dataset.

Comment: @ASpotySpot Updated with my RDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't afford the extra time to complete this, but can give you a start.

The idea is that you aggregate the `RDD[Row]` down into a single Map that represents your JSON structure. Aggregation is a fold that requires two function parameters:

1. `seqOp` How to fold a collection of elements into the target type
2. `combOp` How to merge two of the target types.

The tricky part comes in `combOp` while merging, as you need to accumulate the counts of values seen in the `seqOp`. I have left this as an exercise, as I have a plane to catch! Hopefully someone else can fill in the gaps if you have trouble.

```
  case class Row(id: Int, country: String, tpe: String)

  def foo: Unit = {

    val rows: RDD[Row] = ???

    def seqOp(acc: Map[Int, (Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int])], r: Row) = {
      acc.get(r.id) match {
        case None => acc.updated(r.id, (Map(r.country, 1), Map(r.tpe, 1)))
        case Some((countries, types)) =>
          val countries_ = countries.updated(r.country, countries.getOrElse(r.country, 0) + 1)
          val types_ = types.updated(r.tpe, types.getOrElse(r.tpe, 0) + 1)
          acc.updated(r.id, (countries_, types_))
      }
    }

    val z = Map.empty[Int, (Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int])]

    def combOp(l: Map[Int, (Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int])], r: Map[Int, (Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int])]) = {
      l.foldLeft(z) { case (acc, (id, (countries, types))) =>
          r.get(id) match {
            case None => acc.updated(id, (countries, types))
            case Some(otherCountries, otherTypes) => 
              // todo - continue by merging countries with otherCountries
              // and types with otherTypes, then update acc
          }
      }
    }

    val summaryMap = rows.aggregate(z) { seqOp, combOp }
```